# How to get the functions that call or access a string in Binary Ninja?

Tags: binary, hopper

I am reversing engineering a program. Right now I was using Hopper.
With Hopper once I find a string I can right click and I have an option call "References to ..."
that will return a list of functions that call or access this data.

[image: Hopper]

When I try to use Binary Ninja. I find the string then I noticed that "Cross Reference" is empty. This is the main reason I don't use Binary Ninja but I want to use it because there are other things I really like.

[image]

Anybody knows if I have to check any specific option or do anything special to get the same result?

Comment: Binary Ninja definitely supports this behavior... try another string that you find in the strings output. I have noticed that string references aren't always recognized correctly though when it doesn't separate them out like that.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I had to contact The guys from Binary Ninja. They said BN does not recognize cfstrings out of the box so I had to install a plugin that recognize them I still wasn't able to see the cross references.